# Is it possible that DictWriter creates a csv file where the order of the header doesn't match the order of the values?

Tags: python

```
new_i = csv.DictWriter(file_obj, fieldnames)
new_i.writeheader()
for item in new_list:
  new_i.writerow(item)
```

It hasn't created an out of order csv file for me yet, but I wanted to know if it could. Couldn't the writerow function write the dictionary values in any order?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, because the writer uses the order of `fieldnames` to produce the rows. This guarantees that all rows use the same order.

This is [explicitly documented](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter):

> The *fieldnames* parameter is a sequence of keys **that identify the order in which values in the dictionary passed to the `writerow()` method are written to file *f***.

Bold emphasis mine. The documentation also links to the source code, where you can [see how this is achieved](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.6.1/Lib/csv.py#L152):

```
return (rowdict.get(key, self.restval) for key in self.fieldnames)
```

At no point is the order of the dictionary consulted.

Comment: [Relevant line of source](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/4243df51fe43/Lib/csv.py#l152).

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: keep up! GitHub is the source of truth for the Python source code these days! :-D (and I already added a link to the very same line).

Comment: They changed *again*? They should make up their minds already :P

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: relevant accepted PEP: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0512/ (although there were a few predecessors that didn't make it).